Two sets of vectors having the same Gram matrix
Let $\{ a_k \}$ and $\{ b_k \}$ be two sets of $n$ vectors of the same dimension, such that
$$\langle a_x, a_y \rangle = \langle b_x, b_y \rangle$$
for every $x, y$. Is it true that there exists a unitary matrix such that
$$a_k = U b_k$$
for every $k$? The converse seems trivial as unitary matrices preserve inner products.
My idea would be by induction on $n$, where the case $n = 1$ seems trivial (just take $U$ that maps $a_1 \rightarrow b_1$ and then complete the two bases with Gram-Schmidt).
But I'm stuck here, on defining the inductive step.

Let $A=\pmatrix{a_1&a_2&\cdots&a_n}$ and define $B$ analogously. By assumption, $A^\ast A=B^\ast B$.
Let $AB^\ast=UP$ be a polar decomposition, where $U$ is unitary and $P$ is positive semidefinite. Then $P^2=BA^\ast AB^\ast=BB^\ast BB^\ast=(BB^\ast)^2$. Therefore $P=BB^\ast$ and $AB^\ast=UBB^\ast$. It follows that $A=UB$ on $\operatorname{range}(B^\ast)$.
Note that $\ker(A)=\ker(B)$ because $A^\ast A=B^\ast B$. So, we also have $A=UB$ on $\operatorname{range}(B^\ast)^\perp=\ker(B)=\ker(A)$. Now the result follows.

Crystal clear, thanks. This generalizes to separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, right?

@NYG If the two sets of vectors are finite, yes. This basically has nothing to do with the dimension or separability of the Hilbert space (say, $\mathcal H$), because  $\mathcal V=\operatorname{span}{a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n}$ is finite-dimensional. Once an isometry $U$ on $\mathcal V$ is constructed such that $a_j=Ub_j$ for each $j$, one may extend $U$ to an isometry on the ambient Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, because $\mathcal H=\mathcal V\oplus\mathcal V^\perp$ by the closeness of $\mathcal V$.

Yes it makes sense. I was wondering about the case where the set of vectors is infinite, even uncountably infinite. My guess is that this also extends to the countably infinite case, but I'm not sure if I have, say, two functions $a(x), b(x)$, where $x \in [0, 1]$.

I assume you are talking about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here is a starting point that may help: Let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$, and let $B$ be the matrix with as columns $b_1, \ldots, b_k$. Your condition is equivalent to saying that $A^TA=B^TB$.
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are square, invertible matrices. Then there exists a matrix $U$ such that $A=UB$. Our condition rewrites to $A^TA=B^TU^TUB=B^TB$, or in other words $B^T(U^TU-I)B=0$. But as $B$ is invertible, this means that $(U^TU-I)B=0$, and using invertibility again we get $U^TU-I=0$. And that means that $U$ is a unitary matrix, so the statement is true for square matrices.

This only proves that if there exists a $U$ that satisfies the condition, then it must be unitary, but still doesn't seem to guarantee that it exists
